# Any risk to changing WP table col CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH?

Tags: database

I made a li'l module to help myself develop sites for various clients, and one thing it provides is an easy template for custom post types. It allows me to register post types much more easily and handles a lot of the default values I'd otherwise have to set up to get a nice post listing page and so forth.

Currently, it allows post type IDs of arbitrary lengths. I don't remember why I made this decision three years ago when I wrote the module, but in order to achieve this, it has to expand the `wp_posts -> post_type` column in the event that the desired `post_type` value is greater than `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`.

Well, lo & behold, today I visited a site I worked on and somehow or other (an auto security update released before 5.5 maybe?), various things were broken. On investigation, the `post_type` values had been clipped, resulting in nothing coming out of the query.

Did WP reset the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH perhaps? Is what I'm doing an unstable way of solving this problem (as opposed to, say, clipping or hashing `post_type` values to preserve arbitrary length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post_type` field  is an internal feld, you shouldn't be giving it values that  require longer column lengths, and there's no need for it to be user facing.

WP allows you to override everything about it, from the query variable name, rewrite rules, to the wording displayed.

But more importantly, you shouldn't modify WP core. That goes for the database table schema too. WP will overwrite your changes when it calls `dbDelta` and restores the canonical database schema as part of the update process. At which point your column will get truncated. You might be able to get away with adding indexes at best, adding custom tables is fine.

So:

> Did WP reset the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH perhaps?

Yes

> Is what I'm doing an unstable way of solving this problem?

Yes

> (as opposed to, say, clipping or hashing post_type values to preserve arbitrary length)

You shouldn't need more than  20 characters for a `post_type`, perhaps your auto-generated post type names are too verbose.

I wrote a plugin that registered thousands of custom post types in order to answer a question asked on this site, you'll face major PHP memory and performance issues long before you exhaust the 20 character namespace ( generating and transferring the markup for the admin menu gets problematic after 200, it breaks at a certain point, past 1000 it struggles despite no actual posts in the database for the CPT's

Comment: Makes sense. This module isn't user-facing (more of an anti-corruption layer... an imperfect one, clearly), but the naming scheme for post types definitely is too verbose. Thanks for clearing that up!